# Mouse as joystick in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to create a custom control such that a mouse can be used as joystick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this may help you [Joystick](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ldrolet/MouseStick06132005031337AM/MouseStick.aspx)